# Where to find a reliable K-medoid(Not k-means) open source software/tool?

Tags: open-source, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am learning the K-medoids algorithm so I am sorry if I ask inappropriate questions. As I know,the K-medoids algorithm implements a K-means clustering but use actual data points to be centroid instead of mathematical calculated means.

As I googled online, I found a lot of k-means tools such as GenePattern, geWengh,...etc but not the k-medoids ones. Some nice friends has showed me that at Matlab, there is also one written by some user. However, I am afraid that personal implemented tool may still have some bugs or limitations. Thus, I am wondering if there is some widely used reliable open source software/tools  which uses actual data points as centroids to cluster. I need to find out the information about actual centroids so only returning clustering results is not enough. I prefer website online ones but if this is not the case, I am ok to install it to my local machine. Thank you very much,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. A k-medoid implmentation in C is available in the [C Clustering Library](http://bonsai.hgc.jp/~mdehoon/software/cluster/software.htm#source) ([source](http://bonsai.hgc.jp/~mdehoon/software/cluster/cluster-1.50.tar.gz), [Manual](http://bonsai.hgc.jp/~mdehoon/software/cluster/cluster.pdf)). (note that Cluster 3.0 is an extension of this library, and may not provide k-medoids)

   From the manual:

   > > In the C Clustering Library, three partitioning algorithms are available:
   > >     • k-means clustering
   > >     • k-medians clustering
   > >     • **k-medoids** clustering
2. [k-medoids in mlpy, Machine Learning library in Python](https://mlpy.fbk.eu/)
3. [k-medoids in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28898)
4. [k-medoids in Java](http://www.hackchina.com/en/cont/52290)
5. [k-medoids in C++](http://forums.about.com/n/pfx/forum.aspx?tsn=1&nav=messages&webtag=ab-cplus&tid=3777)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I know, k-medians is different from k-medoids. In addition, the Cluster 3.0 tool does not return the centroids as original data points. If I am wrong, please correct me. About other programs and codes, they are nice. However, since they are written by individual persons not by labs such as GenePattern or Cluster3.0, I am a little bit concern about the limitation of them. Anyway, if there is no other solution, I will try to use software from individuals.

Comment: @Cassie , The C Clustering Library is a prequel of Cluster 3.0, and it is provided by the same authors in that same page. *k-medoids* (and k-medians) is provided there. Also, *mlpy* is not written by an individual.

Comment: The R library cluster provide both k-means and k-medoids.

Comment: I can't find any k-medoids in mlpy. Has it disappeared? Or does it have another name?

Answer (score 2):

**Software:**

- ELKI includes several k-means variants, including K-medoids and PAM.
- GNU R includes on the "flexclust" package variants of k-means and on the "cluster" package.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids

Answer (score 0):

For Python, I've found a package that implements PAM and Clara: [PyCluster](http://daveti.blog.com/2013/06/13/pycluster-python-clustering/)