# Iregular plot of k-means clustering, outlier removal

Tags: matlab, plot, data-mining, cluster-analysis, k-means

Hi I'm working on trying to cluster network data from the 1999 darpa data set. Unfortunately I'm not really getting clustered data, not compared to some of the literature, using the same techniques and methods.

My data comes out like this:

[image: Matlab Figure 1]

As you can see, it is not very Clustered. This is due to a lot of outliers (noise) in the dataset. I have looked at some outlier removal techniques but nothing I have tried so far really cleans the data. One of the methods I have tried:

```
%% When an outlier is considered to be more than three standard deviations away from the mean, determine the number of outliers in each column of the count matrix:

    mu = mean(data)
    sigma = std(data)
    [n,p] = size(data);
    % Create a matrix of mean values by replicating the mu vector for n rows
    MeanMat = repmat(mu,n,1);
    % Create a matrix of standard deviation values by replicating the sigma vector for n rows
    SigmaMat = repmat(sigma,n,1);
    % Create a matrix of zeros and ones, where ones indicate the location of outliers
    outliers = abs(data - MeanMat) > 3*SigmaMat;
    % Calculate the number of outliers in each column
    nout = sum(outliers) 
    % To remove an entire row of data containing the outlier
    data(any(outliers,2),:) = [];
```

In the first run, it removed 48 rows from the 1000 normalized random rows which are selected from the full dataset.

This is the full script I used on the data:

```
    %% load data
        %# read the list of features
        fid = fopen('kddcup.names','rt');
        C = textscan(fid, '%s %s', 'Delimiter',':', 'HeaderLines',1);
        fclose(fid);

        %# determine type of features
        C{2} = regexprep(C{2}, '.$','');              %# remove "." at the end
        attribNom = [ismember(C{2},'symbolic');true]; %# nominal features

        %# build format string used to read/parse the actual data
        frmt = cell(1,numel(C{1}));
        frmt( ismember(C{2},'continuous') ) = {'%f'}; %# numeric features: read as number
        frmt( ismember(C{2},'symbolic') ) = {'%s'};   %# nominal features: read as string
        frmt = [frmt{:}];
        frmt = [frmt '%s'];                           %# add the class attribute

        %# read dataset
        fid = fopen('kddcup.data_10_percent_corrected','rt');
        C = textscan(fid, frmt, 'Delimiter',',');
        fclose(fid);

        %# convert nominal attributes to numeric
        ind = find(attribNom);
        G = cell(numel(ind),1);
        for i=1:numel(ind)
            [C{ind(i)},G{i}] = grp2idx( C{ind(i)} );
        end

        %# all numeric dataset
        fulldata = cell2mat(C);

%% dimensionality reduction 
columns = 6
[U,S,V]=svds(fulldata,columns);

%% randomly select dataset
rows = 1000;
columns = 6;

%# pick random rows
indX = randperm( size(fulldata,1) );
indX = indX(1:rows)';

%# pick random columns
indY = indY(1:columns);

%# filter data
data = U(indX,indY);

% apply normalization method to every cell
maxData = max(max(data));
minData = min(min(data));
data = ((data-minData)./(maxData));

% output matching data
dataSample = fulldata(indX, :)

%% When an outlier is considered to be more than three standard deviations away from the mean, use the following syntax to determine the number of outliers in each column of the count matrix:

mu = mean(data)
sigma = std(data)
[n,p] = size(data);
% Create a matrix of mean values by replicating the mu vector for n rows
MeanMat = repmat(mu,n,1);
% Create a matrix of standard deviation values by replicating the sigma vector for n rows
SigmaMat = repmat(sigma,n,1);
% Create a matrix of zeros and ones, where ones indicate the location of outliers
outliers = abs(data - MeanMat) > 2.5*SigmaMat;
% Calculate the number of outliers in each column
nout = sum(outliers) 
% To remove an entire row of data containing the outlier
data(any(outliers,2),:) = [];

%% generate sample data
K = 6;
numObservarations = size(data, 1);
dimensions = 3;

%% cluster
opts = statset('MaxIter', 100, 'Display', 'iter');
[clustIDX, clusters, interClustSum, Dist] = kmeans(data, K, 'options',opts, ...
'distance','sqEuclidean', 'EmptyAction','singleton', 'replicates',3);

%% plot data+clusters
figure, hold on
scatter3(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3), 5, clustIDX, 'filled')
scatter3(clusters(:,1),clusters(:,2),clusters(:,3), 100, (1:K)', 'filled')
hold off, xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), zlabel('z')
grid on
view([90 0]);

%% plot clusters quality
figure
[silh,h] = silhouette(data, clustIDX);
avrgScore = mean(silh);
```

This is two distinct clusters from the output:

[image]

As you can see the data looks cleaner and more clustered than the original. However I still think a better method can be used.

For instance observing the overall clustering, I still have a lot of noise (outliers) from the dataset. As can be seen here:

[image]

I need the outlier rows put into a seperate dataset for later classification (only removed from the clustering)

Here is a link to the darpa dataset, please note that the 10% data set has had significant reduction in columns, a majority of columns which have 0 or 1's running through-out have been removed (42 columns to 6 columns):

http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/kddcup99/kddcup99.html

**EDIT**

Columns kept in the dataset are:

```
src_bytes: continuous.

dst_bytes: continuous.

count: continuous.

srv_count: continuous.  

dst_host_count: continuous.

dst_host_srv_count: continuous.
```

**RE-EDIT:**

Based on discussions with Anony-Mousse and his answer, there may be a way of reducing noise in the clustering using K-Medoids http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids. I'm hoping that there isnt much of a change in the code that I currently have but as of yet I do not know how to implement it to test whether this will significantly reduce the noise. So providing that someone can show me a working example this will be accepted as an answer.

Comment: it doesn't seem like your data is very clustered.. seems like a big blob and some points around it. what do you expect the clustering algorithm to do? if you want to separate the middle from the outliers, maybe hierarchical clustering will do better.

Comment: can you put a link to an example about this data? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @Ran hey updated question with a link to the data.

Comment: Don't squeeze the plot, and it will look better!

Comment: @JungleBoogie: what have you tried yourself? Most of the code above is simply [reusing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7721674/97160) [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7782316/97160) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1400760/97160). While this is fine, your are now basically asking us to implement outlier detection for you. Your question as stated doesn't show the effort you may have made in searching for a solution. Unfortunately, posting a big reward does not change that fact.

Comment: @JungleBoogie: Plus your question is too vague and possibly off-topic. For example, how do you define outliers, and what do you expect the correct result of clustering to be. After all, in exploratory data analysis there is no single correct answer. I'm inclined towards voting to close..

Comment: @JungleBoogie: the error you are getting is because you did not update `numObservarations` after you removed rows from the dataset. FWIW the whole section "Assign data to clusters" is not needed, I simply had it in the original post to show how to compute distances between instances and centroids. That information is already provided by `kmeans` in the `clustIDX` argument

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First things first: you're asking for a lot here. For future reference: try to break up your problem in smaller chunks, and post several questions. This increases your chances of getting answers (and doesn't cost you 400 reputation!).

Luckily for you, I understand your predicament, and just love this sort of question!

Apart from this dataset's possible issues with k-means, this question is still generic enough to apply also to other datasets (and thus Googlers ending up here looking for a similar thing), so let's go ahead and get this solved.

My suggestion is we edit this answer until you get reasonably satisfactory results.

## Number of clusters

Step 1 of any clustering problem: how many clusters to choose? There are a few methods I know of with which you can select the proper number of clusters. There is a nice [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set) about this, containing all of the methods below (and a few more).

### Visual inspection

It might seem silly, but if you have well-separated data, a simple plot can tell you already (approximately) how many clusters you'll need, just by looking.

Pros:

- quick
- simple
- works well on well-separated clusters in relatively small datasets

Cons:

- and dirty
- requires user interaction
- it's easy to miss smaller clusters
- data with less-well separated clusters, or very many of them, are hard to do by this method
- it is all rather subjective -- the next person might select a different amount than you did.

### silhouettes plot

As indicated in  one of your [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384430/show-rows-on-clustered-kmeans-data), making a `silhouettes` plot will help you make a better decision about the proper number of clusters in your data.

Pros:

- relatively simple
- reduces subjectivity by using statistical measures
- intuitive way to represent quality of the choice

Cons:

- requires user interaction
- In the limit, if you take as many clusters as there are datapoints, a silhouettes plot will tell you that *that* is the best choice
- it is still rather subjective, not based on statistical means
- can be computationally expensive

### elbow method

As with the silhouettes plot approach, you run `kmeans` repeatedly, each time with a larger amount of clusters, and you see how much of the total variance in the data is explained by the clusters chosen by this `kmeans` run. There will be a number of clusters where the amount of explaned variance will suddenly increase a lot less than in any of the previous choices of the number of clusters (the "elbow"). The elbow is then statistically speaking the best choice for the number of clusters.

Pros:

- no user interaction required -- the elbow can be selected automatically
- statistically more sound than any of the aforementioned methods

Cons:

- somewhat complicated
- *still* subjective, since the definition of the "elbow" depends on subjectively chosen parameters
- can be computationally expensive

## Outliers

Once you have chosen the number of clusters with any of the methods above, it is time to do outlier detection to see if the quality of your clusters improves.

I would start by a two-step-iterative approach, using the elbow method. In pseudo-Matlab:

```
data = your initial dataset
dataMod = your initial dataset

MAX = the number of clusters chosen by visual inspection

while (forever)

    for N = MAX-5 : MAX+5
        if (N < 1), continue, end
        perform k-means with N clusters on dataMod
        if (variance explained shows a jump)
            break
    end

    if (you are satisfied)
        break
    end

    for i = 1:N
        extract all points from cluster i 
        find the centroid (let k-means do that)
        calculate the standard deviation of distances to the centroid
        mark points further than 3 sigma as possible outliers
    end

    dataMod = data with marked points removed

end
```

The tough part is obviously determining whether `you are satisfied`. 
This is the key to the algorithm's effectiveness. The rough structure of 
this part

```
if (you are satisfied)
    break
end
```

would be something like this

```
if (situation has improved)
    data = dataMod

elseif (situation is same or worse)
    dataMod = data
    break            
end
```

the `situation has improved` when there are fewer outliers, or the variance 
explaned for ALL choices of `N` is better than during the previous loop in the `while`. This is also something to fiddle with.

Anyway, much more than a first attempt I wouldn't call this. 
If anyone sees incompletenesses, flaws or loopholes here, please 
comment or edit.

Comment: You probably remove *normal* data from the data set with this "outlier removal". The normal data is much more spread out; the attack data comes in massive burst (and makes up 80% of the data set) that cluster somewhat and that is much more self-similar.

Answer (score 10):

Note that using this dataset is *discouraged*:

That dataset has errors: [KDD Cup '99 dataset (Network Intrusion) considered harmful](http://www.kdnuggets.com/news/2007/n18/4i.html)

Reconsider using a different algorithm. k-means is not really appropriate for mixed-type data, where many attributes are *discrete*, and have very different scales. K-means needs to be able to compute *sensible* means. And for a binary vector "0.5" is not a sensible mean, it should be either 0 or 1.

Plus, k-means doesn't like outliers too much.

When plotting, make sure to scale them equally, or the result will look incorrect. You X-axis has a length of around 0.9, your y axis only 0.2 - no wonder they look squashed.

Overall, **maybe the data set just doesn't have k-means-style clusters?** You definitely should try a density-based methods (because these *can* deal with outliers) such as DBSCAN. But judging from the visualizations you added, I'd say it has at most 4-5 clusters, and they are not really interesting. They probably can be captured with a number of thresholds in some dimensions.

[image: Parallel coordinates]

Here is a visualization of the data set after z-normalization, visualized in parallel coordinates, with 5000 samples. Bright green is normal.

You can clearly see special properties of the data set. All of the attacks are clearly different in attributes 3 and 4 (count and srv_count) and also most very concentrated in dst_host_count and dst_host_srv_count.

I've ran OPTICS on this data set, too. It found a number of clusters, most of them in the wine-colored attack pattern. But they're not really interesting. If you have 10 different hosts ping-flooding, they will form 10 clusters.

[image: OPTICS Clusters]

You can see very well that [OPTICS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPTICS_algorithm) managed to cluster a number of these attacks. It missed all the orange stuff (maybe if I had set minpts lower, it is quite spread out) but it even discovered *structure within the wine-colored attack), breaking it into a number of separate events.

To *really* make sense of this data set, you should **start with feature extraction**, for example by merging such ping flood connection attempts into an *aggregate event*.

Also note that **this is an unrealistic scenario**.

1. There are well-known patterns involved in attacks, in particular *port scans*. These are best detected with a specialized port scan detector, not with *learning*.
2. The simulated data has a lot of completely pointless "attacks" simulated. For example [Smurf attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smurf_attack) from the 90s, is >50% of the data set, and Syn flood is another 20%; while normal traffic is <20%!
3. For these kind of attacks, there are well-known signatures.
4. Much of modern attacks (SQL injection, for example) flow with usual HTTP traffic, and will not show up anomalous in raw traffic pattern.

Just **don't use this data for classification or outlier detection**. Just don't.

Quoting the KDNuggets link above:

> As a result, we strongly recommend that
>
> (1) all researchers stop using the KDD Cup '99 dataset,
>
> (2) The KDD Cup and UCI websites include a warning on the KDD Cup '99 dataset webpage informing researchers that there are known problems with the dataset, and
>
> (3) peer reviewers for conferences and journals ding papers (or even outright **reject** them, as is common in the network security community) with results drawn solely from the KDD Cup '99 dataset.

**This is neither *real* nor *realistic* data. Go get something else.**

Comment: Btw did you take this from the graph alone? As I have used the rotate button to get a better view of the data in which the x n y axis changes.

Comment: Also please note there is no TTL within the data and no data attributes for attacks that result in the majority having numbers of 253 or 126 regardless. If you also look at his references they do not corroborate his attack on the darpa training set either.

Comment: The point is not just that there is this one attribute that is sufficient for classification, but also that it is not *real*, but simulated. So it actually doesn't tell you anything about detecting real intrusions. Or *real network topology*. But nevertheless, I would not expect k-means to work well on this data set, because the clusters just are not k-means-style clusters.

Comment: Im not using K-Means for detecting intrusions im using it for data mining purposes, of which I will later use a proper classification algorithm to classify the attacks and attack types. The mining is important in being able to quickly cluster rows, k-means seems the fastest of the ones I have reviewed. As we speak I am now yielding better results but with alot of outliers. (those outliers being important)

Comment: k-means does not work well with outliers, as I said before. And it does not work well with discrete (or event binary!) attributes. Your result might as well be a random binary split. You probably won't notice.

Comment: I've added some extra plots to visualize the data. There are strong correlations in this data set, that may also pose problems to k-means.

Comment: Its really constructive criticism and as much as it hurts to hear it I am glad your expertise has given a hand in showing the pitfalls of 1) the data 2) k-means. But the question at hand really only asks for a method of outlier removal, nothing else. The outlier removal is a process in many data mining techniques so regardless if the dataset fits with k-means or not or wether my futile attempts at data mining are misguided I still have to learn about outlier removal. So far I only have the approach that I have attempted in my question.

Comment: The question is: what is an outlier. In this data set, the *normal* data are the outliers (they are much more spread out), and the 80% attacks (that occur in bursts) are inliers? No, unless you do some preprocessing to merge packets into events you can't really talk about outliers here either.

Comment: Anony you cant do that in real world traffic analysis so why do it here.

Comment: @JungleBoogie: if you are looking for alternative approaches, read this page on [anomaly detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection). This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2303583/97160) might also be relevant..

Comment: @Anony-Mousse please read the top lines of this page [Outlier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) forget anomaly detection for a moment. DBScan however looks good, but this would require such a long learning process again one of which I cant afford.

Comment: Yes, but why should it make any sense to drop/ignore data when you know that it actually is to be considered normal? Even when analyzing a normal distribution, you should *not* remove the >3*sigma objects, because *if* they belong to the distribution, you will undererstimate the standard deviation when you remove them.
Outliers, anomalies, etc. - you should only remove them when you are convinced that they do come from a *different* data source.
You could still look into DBSCAN/OPTICS that I mentioned. They have a notion of "noise" objects that don't cluster.

Comment: In a sense K-means is already acting as an outlier detection, and I have read a few times that it can and sometimes is used for that, like the question you just posted. Atm I do get well defined clusters but with some noise. Its this noise I am atm classing as outliers which I want to remove.

Comment: Actually I only know statements that say "k-means doesn't work on data that has outliers", and that if you have outliers, you should try using k-medians or k-medoids instead.

Comment: Outlier is defined as a noisy observation, which does not fit to the assumed model that generated the data. In clustering, outliers are considered as observations that should be removed in order to make clustering more reliable. The ability to detect outliers can be improved using a combined perspective of outlier detection and clustering. Some clustering algorithms, for example DBSCAN and ROCK, handle outliers as special observations, but their main concern is clustering the dataset, not detecting outliers. [Kmeans outlier detection](http://cs.joensuu.fi/~villeh/35400978.pdf)

Comment: The simple fact is on this dataset and kmeans, it has been done before I have numerous papers on it. You mention "Yes, but why should it make any sense to drop/ignore data when you know that it actually is to be considered normal?" im not dropping, the outliers are a special case of which they are analysed later by another classification algorithm. This process of clustering is only to segment data into its appropriate distributions of which later another programme (more defined) will inspect those clusters. Each appropriate at that specific target class.

Comment: I just dont nor find it appropriate to tell everyone exactly everything im doing, I only wanted a simple way to remove some noise from Kmeans lol

Comment: Well, the paper you gave is rarely cited, and published on an *image analysis* conference. I wouldn't call this a widely adopted outlier removal method. I'm going to stick with the books that say "don't use k-means, use k-medoids".

Comment: @Anony-Mousse how much different in implementation to what I currently have would k-medoids be? Could you provide an example related to what I have? If it does significantly reduce the noise then your question (provided code is supplied) will be accepted.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medians_clustering and k-medoids in Wikipedia. I cannot give you code as I don't *have* Matlab. I can only give you advice.

Comment: Ok I will put a note in my question about K-medoids based on your expertise. Thanks Anony.

Comment: @JungleBoogie: there is a [k-medoids](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28898-k-medoids) implementation on the File Exchange. A quick Google search would reveal [more](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7667051/97160)...

Comment: @Amro yes the link in the question is to the same source as you provided, but if you look at the comments it has errors :S the first user comment states "SIMPLY NOT working". Its also riddled with some java script. Not touching it.

Comment: @JungleBoogie: don't be too quick to judge. I just tried it myself and it is working as advertised... And I have no idea what Javascript you are talking about, the [code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28898-k-medoids/content/kmedoids.m) is right there in front of you! You don't like it, I can see three other implementations in the first page of a [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=matlab+k-medoids). Better yet implement your own...

Comment: Yeah sorry that one was easy to run my mistake, really dont understand the output tho label, energy, index? +1 aswell thanks for helping.

Comment: What plotting function did you use to make your data visualisations? Something from MATLAB?